# escape single quotes in ffmpeg command

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I have a folder with this exact filepath in window 10:

```
D:\martinradio\rips\vinyl-wip\7.10.23\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band – Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison
```

As you can see there is a single quote in the foldername: `All We Want'sa Prison`

My ffmpeg command has file inputs and file output filepaths surrounded by double quotes, but the single quote in the folder name is causing an issue, when i run the command:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe

 -r 2 -i "D:\martinradio\rips\vinyl-wip\7.10.23\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison\A - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap).flac"

 -r 2 -i "D:\martinradio\rips\vinyl-wip\7.10.23\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison\B - All We Want'sa Prison.flac"

 -r 2 -i "D:\martinradio\rips\vinyl-wip\7.10.23\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison\front.png"

 -r 2 -i "D:\martinradio\rips\vinyl-wip\7.10.23\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison\back.png"

 -r 2 -i "D:\martinradio\rips\vinyl-wip\7.10.23\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison\side_1.png"

 -r 2 -i "D:\martinradio\rips\vinyl-wip\7.10.23\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison\side_2.png" 

 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a];[2:v]scale=w=2000:h=2000:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=1,loop=152.57:152.57[v2];[3:v]scale=w=2000:h=2000:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=1,loop=152.57:152.57[v3];[4:v]scale=w=2000:h=2000:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=1,loop=152.57:152.57[v4];[5:v]scale=w=2000:h=2000:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=1,loop=152.57:152.57[v5];[v2][v3][v4][v5]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]" 

 -map [v] -map [a] -c:a pcm_s32le -c:v libx264 -bufsize 3M -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune stillimage -t 305.15 

 "D:\martinradio\rips\vinyl-wip\7.10.23\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison_427.mkv"
```

I get this error:

```
D:\martinradio\rips\vinyl-wip\7.10.23\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison\A - Is We Is! (The Prison Rap).flac: No such file or directory
```

i believe this error is caused by the single quote char, how do I escaped it so that my command runs? I've tried following the accepted answer here: [Filename quoting in ffmpeg concat](https://superuser.com/questions/787064/filename-quoting-in-ffmpeg-concat)

but the command still failed. Im running this command in powershell

Comment: The following command is working in my machine: `ffmpeg.exe -i "D:\martinradio\rips\vinyl-wip\The Barbed Wire Choir Of Flora, Illinois  Chief Ed Guyott And The Long Arm Of The Law Band – Is We Is! (The Prison Rap)  All We Want'sa Prison.flac" test.mp3` (using PowerShell). Please post a minimal reproducible example (reproduce the issue using a single input file with short name that has a single quote...).